# How can I print out the questions the user got wrong and the questions the user got correct (separately) after completing a quiz in python?

Tags: python, function, printing

How can I print out the questions the user got wrong and the questions the user got correct (separately) after completing a quiz in python?

Comment: That's a fairly nasty block of code to read.  Are you sure there are no functions hidden in that code?  You're going to need a list of the question texts somewhere.  Anyway, you keep a record of the question numbers that were answered correctly (a list of such numbers) and another list of the numbers that were answered incorrectly, and then at the end you can print from the list of questions the ones cited in each list.  You can also identify any questions that were not attempted.

Comment: Can you not store the values in a dictionary? Like 
answers = {'name': 'john', 'true_answers': ['q1','q2'], 'false_answers': [q4,q5] }

Comment: Thanks so much @JonathanLeffler, is there any way that you can show me what you mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna be lazy, you can just keep all of the correct question data in a list, same with the incorrect ones, like in my example below...

Well I did this much of your homework, but I overlooked that there's no support for fill-in-the-blank. You could simply test if the question['answer'] is a string or an integer and then perform the appropriate actions based on that. Enjoy, I was bored!

```
import string


print(("Welcome to the 'So You Think You Can Civics' quiz. This quiz "
       "will test your knowledge on basic civics topics. Let's see "
       "if you were paying attention in Civics class!"))

questions = [
             {
              'question': 'Who is the current Prime Minister of Canada?',
              'options': ['Jean Chretien', 'Stephen Harper', 'Cam Guthrie',
                          'Dalton McGuinty', 'Steve Jobs'],
              'answer': 1,  # refers to the index of answer in options
             }
            ]

users_correct_questions = []
users_incorrect_questions = []
score = 0

for question in questions:
    print('\n' + question['question'])

    for i, option in enumerate(question['options']):
        print(string.ascii_lowercase[i] + ' ' + option)

    # selection must be between 0 and len(options) - 1
    viable_range = string.ascii_lowercase[:len(question['options'])]
    user_answer = 'Z'  # well, it'll never be this! :p

    while user_answer not in viable_range:
        user_answer = raw_input('Answer: ')#.lowercase()

    question['user_answer'] = user_answer

    if string.ascii_lowercase.index(user_answer) == question['answer']:
        score += 1
        users_correct_questions.append(question)
        print('Correct!')

    else:
        print('False!')
        users_incorrect_questions.append(question)

# let's print out each question which was incorrect, first!
if users_incorrect_questions:
    print("You got the following questions wrong...")

    for question in users_incorrect_questions:
        print("Question: " + question['question'])
        print("Your Answer: " + question['user_answer'])
        print("Correct Answer: " + question['options'][question['answer']])

# let's print out each question which was correct!
if users_correct_questions:
    print("\nYou got the following questions correct...\n")

    for question in users_correct_questions:
        print("Question: " + question['question'])
        print("Your Answer: " + question['user_answer'])

# Statistics
print("\nYour score is: %d out of %d" % (score, len(questions)))
percentage = (score / len(questions)) * 100
print("The percentage of questions answered correctly is %s%%" % percentage)
print('Thanks for completing the "So You Think You Can Civics" quiz!')
```

Answer (score 0):

This more or less works, I think.  And there's definitely a slightly more complex data structure and a lot less code crying to escape from the repetition in this material.

```
cont = ""

questions = [
    "What is the Zeroth Law of Thermodynamics?",
    "Who is the current Prime Minister of Canada?",
    "Which document outlines the specific rights guaranteed to all Canadian citizens?",
    "Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?",
    "Which of the following is not a Fundamental Freedom?",
    "(Fill in the blank) The three levels of government are Federal, Provincial and _______?",
    "(Fill in the blank) A two-house system of government is called ________?",
]

def get_answer(prompt):
    answer = input(prompt).lower()
    while not answer.isalpha():
        answer = input(prompt).lower()
    return answer

while cont != "n":
    score = 0
    qnum = 0
    right = []
    wrong = []
    print("Welcome to the 'So You Think You Can Civics' quiz.")
    print("This quiz will test your knowledge on basic civics topics.")
    print("Let's see if you were paying attention in Civics class!")

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        print(" a) Jean Chretien", "\n","b) Stephen Harper", "\n", "c) Cam Guthrie", "\n", "d) Dalton McGuinty", "\n", "e) Steve Jobs")
        answer = get_answer("Make your choice: ")
        if answer == "b":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        wrong.append(qnum)
        print("Out of Chances!")

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        print(" a) The Universal Declaration of Human Rights", "\n", "b) The American Constitution", "\n", "c) The Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms", "\n", "d) The Ontario Human Rights Code", "\n", "e) The Convention on the Rights of the child")
        answer = get_answer("Make your choice: ")
        if answer == "c":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances!")
        wrong.append(qnum)

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        print(" a) Municipal\n", "b) Federal\n", "c) Provincial\n", "d) All\n", "e) Legislative")
        answer = get_answer("Make your choice: ")
        if answer == "d":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances!")
        wrong.append(qnum)

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        print(" a) Presumed innocent until proven guilty", "\n", "b) Conscience and Religion", "\n", "c) Opinion and Expression", "\n", "d) Assembly and Association", "\n", "e) Freedom of peaceful assembly")
        answer = get_answer("Make your choice: ")
        if answer == "a":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances!")
        wrong.append(qnum)

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        answer = get_answer("Enter your answer: ")
        if answer == "municipal":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances!")
        wrong.append(qnum)

    qnum = qnum + 1
    for tries in range(2):
        print("\nQUESTION ", qnum, ":\n", questions[qnum])
        answer = get_answer("Enter your answer: ")
        if answer == "bicameral":
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        print("Out of Chances!")
        wrong.append(qnum)

    print("Your score is: ", score,"/6")
    percent = (score/6)*100
    print(("Your percentage is:{0:2.0f} ".format(percent)),"%")

    if len(right) > 0:
        print("You got these questions right:")
        for r in range(len(right)):
            print(" ", right[r], ": ", questions[right[r]])

    if len(wrong) > 0:
        print("You got these questions wrong:")
        for w in range(len(wrong)):
            print(" ", wrong[w], ": ", questions[wrong[w]])

    cont = input("Continue (y) or (n):")

print("\nThanks for completing the 'So You Think You Can Civics' quiz!")
```

(Note that in the original, as long as you get at least one question right on each iteration of the quiz, you will eventually reach 100% correct.  You don't get that grace with this revision.)

Sample run:

```
$ python3 quiz.py
Welcome to the 'So You Think You Can Civics' quiz.
This quiz will test your knowledge on basic civics topics.
Let's see if you were paying attention in Civics class!

QUESTION  1 :
 Who is the current Prime Minister of Canada?
 a) Jean Chretien 
 b) Stephen Harper 
 c) Cam Guthrie 
 d) Dalton McGuinty 
 e) Steve Jobs
Make your choice: b
Correct!

QUESTION  2 :
 Which document outlines the specific rights guaranteed to all Canadian citizens?
 a) The Universal Declaration of Human Rights 
 b) The American Constitution 
 c) The Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms 
 d) The Ontario Human Rights Code 
 e) The Convention on the Rights of the child
Make your choice: b
False!

QUESTION  2 :
 Which document outlines the specific rights guaranteed to all Canadian citizens?
 a) The Universal Declaration of Human Rights 
 b) The American Constitution 
 c) The Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms 
 d) The Ontario Human Rights Code 
 e) The Convention on the Rights of the child
Make your choice: b
False!
Out of Chances!

QUESTION  3 :
 Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?
 a) Municipal
 b) Federal
 c) Provincial
 d) All
 e) Legislative
Make your choice: d
Correct!

QUESTION  4 :
 Which of the following is not a Fundamental Freedom?
 a) Presumed innocent until proven guilty 
 b) Conscience and Religion 
 c) Opinion and Expression 
 d) Assembly and Association 
 e) Freedom of peaceful assembly
Make your choice: a
Correct!

QUESTION  5 :
 (Fill in the blank) The three levels of government are Federal, Provincial and _______?
Enter your answer: munch
False!

QUESTION  5 :
 (Fill in the blank) The three levels of government are Federal, Provincial and _______?
Enter your answer: municipal
Correct!

QUESTION  6 :
 (Fill in the blank) A two-house system of government is called ________?
Enter your answer: bickering
False!

QUESTION  6 :
 (Fill in the blank) A two-house system of government is called ________?
Enter your answer: unicameral
False!
Out of Chances!
Your score is:  4 /6
Your percentage is:67  %
You got these questions right:
  1 :  Who is the current Prime Minister of Canada?
  3 :  Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?
  4 :  Which of the following is not a Fundamental Freedom?
  5 :  (Fill in the blank) The three levels of government are Federal, Provincial and _______?
You got these questions wrong:
  2 :  Which document outlines the specific rights guaranteed to all Canadian citizens?
  6 :  (Fill in the blank) A two-house system of government is called ________?
Continue (y) or (n):n

Thanks for completing the 'So You Think You Can Civics' quiz!
$
```

#### Structured rewrite

Here's a structured version of the code; it should be pretty simple to add an arbitrary number of extra questions, to select a subset of the available questions, to randomize the order in which the questions are presented, to only ask questions which they got wrong on the previous iteration, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

questions = [

    {   'question': "Who is the current Prime Minister of Canada?",
        'correct': "b",
        'options': [
            "a) Jean Chretien",
            "b) Stephen Harper",
            "c) Cam Guthrie",
            "d) Dalton McGuinty",
            "e) Steve Jobs",
        ],
    },

    {   'question': "Which document outlines the specific rights guaranteed to all Canadian citizens?",
        'correct': "c",
        'options': [
            "a) The Universal Declaration of Human Rights",
            "b) The American Constitution",
            "c) The Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms",
            "d) The Ontario Human Rights Code",
            "e) The Convention on the Rights of the child",
        ],
    },

    {   'question': "Which level of government is responsible for Tourism?",
        'correct': "d",
        'options': [
            "a) Municipal",
            "b) Federal",
            "c) Provincial",
            "d) All",
            "e) Legislative",
        ],
    },

    {   'question': "Which of the following is not a Fundamental Freedom?",
        'correct': "a",
        'options': [
            "a) Presumed innocent until proven guilty",
            "b) Conscience and Religion",
            "c) Opinion and Expression",
            "d) Assembly and Association",
            "e) Freedom of peaceful assembly",
        ],
    },

    {   'question': "The three levels of government are Federal, Provincial and ________?",
        'correct': "municipal",
    },

    {   'question': "A two-house system of government is called ________?",
        'correct': "bicameral",
    },

]

right = []
wrong = []

def get_answer(prompt):
    answer = input(prompt).lower()
    while not answer.isalpha():
        answer = input(prompt).lower()
    return answer

def ask_question(qnum, qinfo):
    score = 0
    for tries in range(2):
        fitb = ""
        prompt = "Make your choice: "
        if not qinfo.get('options'):
            fitb = "(Fill in the blank)"
            prompt = "Enter your answer: "
        print("\nQUESTION", qnum, ":", fitb, qinfo['question'])
        if qinfo.get('options'):
            for opt in qinfo['options']:
                print(" ", opt)
        answer = get_answer(prompt)
        if answer == qinfo['correct']:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
            right.append(qnum)
            break
        else:
            print("False!")
    else:
        wrong.append(qnum)
        print("Out of Chances!")
    return score

def right_wrong(tag, qnos):
    if len(qnos) > 0:
        print("You got these questions", tag, ":")
        for n in range(len(qnos)):
            print(" ", qnos[n], ": ", questions[qnos[n]-1]['question'])

quiz = "'So You Think You Can Civics'"
cont = ""
while cont != "n":
    cont = "n"
    score = 0
    qnum = 0
    right = []
    wrong = []
    print("Welcome to the", quiz, "quiz.")
    print("This quiz will test your knowledge on basic civics topics.")
    print("Let's see if you were paying attention in civics class!")

    num_q = len(questions)
    for qnum in range(num_q):
        score += ask_question(qnum + 1, questions[qnum])

    print("")
    print("Your score is: ", score, "/", num_q)
    percent = (score / num_q) * 100
    print(("Your percentage is: {0:2.0f} ".format(percent)), "%")

    right_wrong("right", right)
    right_wrong("wrong", wrong)

    if score < num_q:
        cont = input("\nContinue (y) or (n): ")

print("\nThanks for completing the", quiz, "quiz!")
```

There are no claims that this code is perfect, but it is a lot more organized and Pythonic than the previous version.